# Document Library column header copy

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csv, copy-and-paste

For a Document Library I would like to copy all the column headers including the managed metadata column headers and past them in another site's Document Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only want to hold the header, you can save this library as a library template including the content (Library settings > Save document library as template ).Download the template in the list template gallery.

Upload this library template to the site collection Site settings > Web Designer Galleries > List templates, then create a new library based on it.

Comment: Creating the template works as you say however the "then create a new library based on it." is now my problem. You got me half the distance and thank you for that Jerry.

Comment: @LesjtayLe After uploading the template, just go to site contents ,add new app, directly search for the name of the template, then you can add a new library based on that template. Sorry for skipping that step.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Jerry